# How could show result particular item in ListView

Tags: java, android

I want Total calculate price in food from Listview.

If you select multiple food iteam and press Order button.

You get Result total price.

How can show my total price please help me.

I am beginner of android.Please help me

#### MenuListItem:

```
package com.example.resturetnordering;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData.Item;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MenuListItem extends Activity{


    ListView lv;
    MyAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);

    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    adapter=new MyAdapter(this , getListItem());
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

//          String ls= lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
//          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(ls) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//            
            adapter.toggleChecked(position);

        }


    });




    }


    public void order(View v) {

        String result="";
        Integer a;
        int r;

        ArrayList<ListItem> res=getListItem();
        List<Integer> resultList=adapter.getCheckedItemPosition();
        for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++) {
            result+=String.valueOf(resultList.get(i))+"\n"; 


        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




    }


    public ArrayList<ListItem> getListItem() {
        ArrayList<ListItem> alllist=new ArrayList<ListItem>();

        ListItem l1=new ListItem("beef_burguer", 1, R.drawable.beef_burguer);
        ListItem l2=new ListItem("bacon_cheese_burger", 2, R.drawable.bacon_cheese_burger);
        ListItem l3=new ListItem("frings", 3, R.drawable.frings);
        ListItem l4=new ListItem("burger_kingse", 4, R.drawable.burger_kingse);
        ListItem l5=new ListItem("mint_oreo", 5, R.drawable.mint_oreo);
        ListItem l6=new ListItem("sourdough_bread", 6, R.drawable.sourdough_bread);
        ListItem l7=new ListItem("sandwich", 7, R.drawable.sandwich);
        ListItem l8=new ListItem("sandwich_loaded", 8, R.drawable.sandwich_loaded);
        ListItem l9=new ListItem("mustard", 9, R.drawable.mustard);
        ListItem l10=new ListItem("cheese_burger", 10, R.drawable.cheese_burger);

        alllist.add(l1);
        alllist.add(l2);
        alllist.add(l3);
        alllist.add(l4);
        alllist.add(l5);
        alllist.add(l6);
        alllist.add(l7);
        alllist.add(l8);
        alllist.add(l9);
        alllist.add(l10);

        return alllist;
    }





}
```

#### ListItem:

```
package com.example.resturetnordering;

public class ListItem {

    String name;
    Integer price;
    Integer image;



    public ListItem(String name, Integer price, Integer image) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.image = image;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(Integer price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public Integer getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(Integer image) {
        image = image;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ListItem [name=" + name + ", price=" + price + ", Image="
                + image + "]";
    }



}
```

#### MyAdapter:

```
package com.example.resturetnordering;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItem>{

     Activity context;
        ArrayList<ListItem> listItem;

        HashMap<Integer, Boolean> myChecked=new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

        public MyAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<ListItem> listItem) {
            super(context, R.layout.adaptermy_layout, listItem);
             this.context=context;
             this.listItem=listItem;

           for (int i = 0; i < listItem.size(); i++) {
            myChecked.put(i, false);
        }

        }

        public void toggleChecked(int position) {
            if(myChecked.get(position)){
                myChecked.put(position, false);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "false", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                myChecked.put(position, true);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "true", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public List<Integer> getCheckedItemPosition() {
            List<Integer> checkedItemPosition=new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for (int i = 0; i < myChecked.size(); i++) {
                if(myChecked.get(i)){
                     checkedItemPosition.add(i);
                }

            }
            return checkedItemPosition;
        }

    //  public List<Integer> getCheckedItem() {
//        List<Integer> checkedItem=new ArrayList<Integer>();
//        
//        for (int i = 0; i < myChecked.size(); i++) {
//            checkedItem.add();
//        }
//        return checkedItem;
    //  }




        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view=convertView;

                LayoutInflater inflat=context.getLayoutInflater();
                view=inflat.inflate(R.layout.adaptermy_layout, null, false);
                TextView txtName=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
                TextView txtPrice=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
                ImageView image=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

                ListItem l=listItem.get(position);

                txtName.setText(l.getName());
                txtPrice.setText(String.valueOf(l.getPrice()));
                image.setImageResource(l.getImage());

                CheckBox chekboxs=(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

                Boolean chekBox=myChecked.get(position);

                if(chekBox!=null){
                    chekboxs.setChecked(chekBox);
                }


            return view;
        }




}
```

Comment: `adapter.getCheckedItemPosition();` returns a list of positions. use that to access the prices in your list of items.

Comment: thanks @njzk2 bro.... please ans ware this i can not understand,I try many thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to perform integer addition(not string) upon prices. Like:

```
public void order(View v) {

    String result="";
    Integer a=0;
    int r=0; // You can use either 'a' or 'r' for addition.

    ArrayList<ListItem> res=getListItem();
    List<Integer> resultList=adapter.getCheckedItemPosition();
    for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++) {
        a+=res.get(resultList.get(i)).getPrice(); 
    }
    result="Total:"+a;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nizam bro..Thanks a lot. but bro i have also a simple problem.When i click checkbox it did not work please tell me??

Comment: Does the Toast appear?